# Cannot open source file endian.h error – what is the problem?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ever since updating to the Ventura public beta I keep getting these kinds of errors:[image]

"cannot open sources file "endian.h" (dependancy of "iostream")"

I also keep getting prompts that clang++ requires the command line tools which I have already installed (when I run xcode-select --install it says that they are alr there). When I click install on the prompt it takes about 5mins (everytime) just to tell me that the software was installed only for me to reopen vscode and for the same install popup to appear and the same error to be present.

I even went and installed the xcode 14.1 beta command line tools (the latest ones) and that didn't seem to fix it either. This was working fine in Monterey before I updated.

Comment: Beta releases are used to find some bugs that can be fixed before the final relase. Pehaps this is what happens here?

Comment: I don't think you are using Microsoft's msvc compiler which the `visual-c++` tag implies. You may be using `visual-studio-code` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ and
look for: "Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1" in the list of downloads then click the dmg download and install it